Is variance always equal to the inverse of the second derivative?
This is the well known formula for estimating parameters of a model based on Fisher Scoring (essentially a statistical version of the Newton-Raphson optimization algorithm):
$$\theta^{(k+1)} = \theta^{(k)} + [I(\theta^{(k)})]^{-1}U(\theta^{(k)})$$
Where:

$\theta^{(k)}$ is the estimate at iteration $k$
$U(\theta)$ is the score function (first derivative of the log-likelihood)
$I(\theta)$ is the Fisher Information matrix (based on the hessian, i.e. second derivatives)

I think the really cool thing about Fisher Scoring is that it simultaneously estimates the variance of the parameters at the same time:
$$E[-\nabla^2 \log L(\theta)] = I(\theta)$$
$$\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}) \approx I^{-1}(\hat{\theta})$$
In previous questions (e.g. How to prevent negative variance estimates in likelihood optimization?), I learned that many software implementations do not actually use this exact Fisher Scoring approach since it can be quite complicated to perform the matrix calculus needed to use the Fisher Scoring approach. Instead, quasi newton approaches such as the BFGS algorithm is used instead.
The BFGS algorithm (has a really similar structure to Fisher Scoring) updates the estimates of $\theta$ as follows:
$$\theta^{(k+1)} = \theta^{(k)} - \alpha^{(k)} H^{(k)} \nabla L(\theta^{(k)})$$
Where:

$\alpha^{(k)}$ is the step size determined by a line search
$H^{(k)}$ is an approximation to the inverse Hessian matrix
$\nabla L(\theta^{(k)})$ is the gradient of the log-likelihood
The gradient $\nabla L(\theta)$ is the same as the score function $U(\theta)$ in Fisher Scoring.

All this makes me wonder. Suppose the final Hessian produced in BFGS (i.e. at convergence) is denoted as $H_{final}$.
Is it then fair to say that?
$$H_{final} \xrightarrow{p} [-\nabla^2 \log L(\theta)]^{-1}$$
$$\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}) \approx H_{final}$$
And ultimately?
$$\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}) \approx \begin{cases} 
I^{-1}(\hat{\theta}) & \text{for Fisher Scoring} \\
H_{final} & \text{for BFGS}
\end{cases}$$
Thus, it appears that the BFGS algorithm also estimates the variance of the parameter estimates (just like Fisher Scoring).
If this is true (i.e. BFGS saves time by avoiding the matrix calculus needed for Fisher Scoring and BFGS still provides variance estimates), then why is Fisher Scoring used at all in applications? It seems to me that Fisher Scoring would only be truly advantageous in some very specific modelling situations (e.g. exponential family, GLM) where we already know the exact matrix calculus needed to populate the score function and expected hessians beforehand? Or perhaps Fisher Scoring is more stable from an optimization perspective and somehow less likely to get stuck compared to BFGS?

It's not necessarily true that BFGS ends up with a good enough approximation to the Hessian. Nor is the calculus to get the true Hessian necessarily difficult, and having an explicit Hessian makes the optimiser less likely to head off in bad directions at the start (when BFGS hasn't built up much of an approximation)
However, yes, Fisher scoring does tend to be used in settings where the expected Fisher information is simpler than the Hessian, such as generalised linear models. Even for the Cox proportional hazards model, where it's common to use a bare-bones Newton-Raphson algorithm, we don't use Fisher scoring because the expectations are hard to calculate.
The big problem with Fisher scoring and straight Newton-Raphson, though, is that they don't work for a lot of problems without very good starting values. You need at least to add the line search step, and perhaps some sort of trust region so that you don't make steps that are too large. And if you're going to do all that, you probably want to use some reliable black-box optimiser such as BFGS or L-BFGS-B.

This was discussed here, i.e. whether it would be possible/worth it to retrieve the approximate Hessian from the BFGS algorithm to use as an approximation of the sampling covariance matrix.
This pull request says in particular:

From a couple experiments with the particular use case I'm interested in, the accuracy of this inverse Hessian approximation is sufficient to give estimates of the standard errors in model parameters that are within ~10-20%, which is better than I had expected (IMHO enough to make this of practical value).

This feature was added to SciPy's L-BFGS-B implementation in 2015. @Galen points out that the API docs for scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b are here.

API Docs: scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.
